# Map column using two dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`:

```
ColA  ColB
1     1
2     3
2     2
1     2
1     3
2     1
```

I would like to use two different dictionaries to change the values in ColB. I would like to use `d1` if the value in ColA is 1 and `d2` if the value in ColB is 2.

```
d1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
d2 = {1:'d',2:'e',3:'f'}
```

Resulting in:

```
ColA  ColB
1     a
2     f
2     e
1     b
1     c
2     d
```

How would be the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to `map` the values in `ColB` using one dictionary or the other depending on the values of `ColA`:

```
import numpy as np
df['ColB'] = np.where(df.ColA.eq(1), df.ColB.map(d1), df.ColB.map(d2))
```

Which gives:

```
    ColA ColB
0     1    a
1     2    f
2     2    e
3     1    b
4     1    c
5     2    d
```

---

For a more general solution, you could use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), which works for multiple conditions. Let's add another value in `ColA` and a dictionary, to see how this could be done with three different mappings:

```
print(df)
    ColA ColB
0     1     1
1     2     3
2     2     2
3     1     2
4     3     3
5     3     1

values_to_map = [1,2,3]
d1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
d2 = {1:'d',2:'e',3:'f'}
d3 = {1:'g',2:'h',3:'i'}

#create a list of boolean Series as conditions
conds = [df.ColA.eq(i) for i in values_to_map]
# List of Series to choose from depending on conds
choices = [df.ColB.map(d) for d in [d1,d2,d3]]
# use np.select to select form the choice list based on conds
df['ColB'] = np.select(conds, choices)
```

Resulting in:

```
    ColA ColB
0     1    a
1     2    f
2     2    e
3     1    b
4     3    i
5     3    g
```

Comment: This does not generalize well.  I suspect the upvotes are for the brevity/succinctness but it isn't very helpful for someone in the future wanting to switch between more than 2 dictionaries.

Comment: Well OP did not really ask for a solution that generalises, but rather for one for this example. However this can easily generalise to multiple cases with `np.select` @piRSquared

Comment: Agree OP didn't ask for it but that is what makes a better answer in my opinion.  And I'd argue that generalizing using `np.select` is not trivial and **is** something you should include.  That would certainly earn my vote.

Comment: Agreed on that :) updated with a more general solution @piRSquared

Answer (score 7):

You can use a new dictionary in which the keys are `tuple`s and map it against the zipped columns.

```
d = {**{(1, k): v for k, v in d1.items()}, **{(2, k): v for k, v in d2.items()}}
df.assign(ColB=[*map(d.get, zip(df.ColA, df.ColB))])

   ColA ColB
0     1    a
1     2    f
2     2    e
3     1    b
4     1    c
5     2    d
```

---

Or we can get cute with a lambda to map.
**NOTE**: I aligned the dictionaries to switch between based on their relative position in the list `[0, d1, d2]`.  In this case it doesn't matter what is in the first position.  I put `0` arbitrarily.

```
df.assign(ColB=[*map(lambda x, y: [0, d1, d2][x][y], df.ColA, df.ColB)])

   ColA ColB
0     1    a
1     2    f
2     2    e
3     1    b
4     1    c
5     2    d
```

---

For robustness I'd stay away from cute and map a lambda that had some default value capability

```
df.assign(ColB=[*map(lambda x, y: {1: d1, 2: d2}.get(x, {}).get(y), df.ColA, df.ColB)])

   ColA ColB
0     1    a
1     2    f
2     2    e
3     1    b
4     1    c
5     2    d
```

Comment: Underrated answer as soon as there are more than two dicts ! +1

Answer (score 4):

If it needs to be done for many groups use a `dict` of `dict`s to map each group separately. Ideally you can find some functional way to create `d`:

```
d = {1: d1, 2: d2}
df['ColB'] = pd.concat([gp.ColB.map(d[idx]) for idx, gp in df.groupby('ColA')])
```

#### Output:

```
   ColA ColB
0     1    a
1     2    f
2     2    e
3     1    b
4     1    c
5     2    d
```

Comment: While I think yatu's answer is most relevant for this specific question, it's good to have the general case solved as well

Comment: Yes, Yatu's solution is very nice and can easily generalize to multiple cases with `np.select`. If one can create the dict of dicts without typing, then I think this might be a bit nicer than all of the listed conditions required for `np.select`

Answer (score 1):

I am using `concat` with `reindex`

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.ColA, df.ColB])
df.ColB=pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in [d1,d2]],keys=[1,2]).reindex(idx).values
df
Out[683]: 
   ColA ColB
0     1    a
1     2    f
2     2    e
3     1    b
4     1    c
5     2    d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that does this for one element and then use an **apply lambda** to your **dataframe**.

```py
def your_func(row):
    if row["ColA"] == 1:
        return d1[row["ColB"]]
    elif row["ColB"] == 2:
        return d2[row["ColB"]]
    else:
        return None

df["ColB"] = df.apply(lambda row: your_func(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Even if this solve the problem, it's going to be pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two replace as such:

```
df.loc[df['ColA'] == 1,'ColB'] = df['ColB'].replace(d1, regex=True)
df.loc[df['ColA'] == 2,'ColB'] = df['ColB'].replace(d2, regex=True)
```

I hope it helps,
BR